# Windows 7: Using schtasks to run on a WinServer2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-tasks

I need to run several scheduled tasks remotely on a WinServer2003 machine. When my OS was WinXP-32 it worked quite fine with a command like "`schtasks /run /s \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /tn ScheduledTaskName`".

Now I upgraded my OS to Win7-64 and I always get errors like "*Host not found*" while with a WinXP system the remote call still works fine.

I have the credentials for a quite powerful user on the server. I can explore its file System without a special login and the command "s`chtasks /query /s \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`" lists all the scheduled tasks on the server correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem. I copied an old version of schtasks.exe (Windows XP 32bit) to my System and used it for the call.
It worked. Weird. Bug or feature?